# Problems with wireless usb mouse on slackware

Tags: linux, usb, mouse, slackware

I have a logitech m570 mouse that I cannot get to work on slackware64 14.1.

My problems began with me being unable to use "X-configure" because of an error with the amount of screens, to create a xorg.conf so I used the graphical interface to generate it. But the default mouse configuration did not work. I can see the mouse and the logitech unifying receiver.

```
$lsusb
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
...
```

But for some reason it detects my keyboard as a mouse and a keyboard and makes 2 different input entries for the same thing essentially. Now I can see the mouse in /dev/usb/ and in /dev but how can I connect those to the xorg.conf when it doesnt show up as an entry in  inputs

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input devices

    I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0566 Product=3107 Version=0110
    N: Name="HID 0566:3107"
    P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
    S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/input/input0
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event0 
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=120013
    B: KEY=1000000000007 ff800000000007ff febeffdff3cfffff fffffffffffffffe
    B: MSC=10
    B: LED=7

    I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0566 Product=3107 Version=0110
    N: Name="HID 0566:3107"
    P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1
    S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/input/input1
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=kbd event1 
    B: PROP=0
    B: EV=1f
    B: KEY=4837fff072ff32d bf54444600000000 1 20f908b17c000 677bfad941dfed   9ed68000004400 10000002
    B: REL=40
    B: ABS=100000000
    B: MSC=10
```

So essentially my mouse doesn't show up in inputs and I would really like to know how I can get it there. I tried to google symlinks and mknod and stuff like that but that didnt seem to be what I was looking for somehow. I tried to edit my xorg.conf to use  /dev/usb/hiddev0 and /dev/hidraw2, so reference them but write a Input device entry, that didnt really work. So I am stuck on how to proceed and any help would be appreciated, I have been trying to get this to work for hours.

```
$dmesg | grep usb
    [    4.023868] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [4.024300] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
    [4.024731] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.10.17 xhci_hcd
    [4.025163] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
    [4.029717] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
    [4.030152] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2,SerialNumber=1
    [4.030584] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
    [4.031013] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.10.17 xhci_hcd
    [4.031442] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
    [4.039385] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
    [4.039832] usbhid: USB HID core driver
    [4.381758] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
    [4.395148] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
    [4.395590] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    [4.396039] usb 1-3: Product: USB Receiver
    [4.396478] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Logitech
    [4.553756] usb 1-4: new low-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
    [4.569918] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0566, idProduct=3107
    [4.570370] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
    [4.570930] usb 1-4: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
    [4.571389] usb 1-4: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
    [4.575143] input: HID 0566:3107 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0   /usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/input/input0
    [4.575693] hid-generic 0003:0566:3107.0004: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [HID 0566:3107] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
    [4.580302] input: HID 0566:3107 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1/input/input1
    [4.580898] hid-generic 0003:0566:3107.0005: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [HID 0566:3107] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1
    [5.191385] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
    [5.192020] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [5.192649] usb usb3: Product: EHCI Host Controller
    [5.193287] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.10.17 ehci_hcd
    [5.193922] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
    [5.195491] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input2
    [5.211771] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
    [5.211773] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [5.211775] usb usb4: Product: EHCI Host Controller
    [5.211777] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.10.17 ehci_hcd
    [5.211778] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
    [5.499746] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
    [5.614125] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8008
    [5.614136] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
    [5.717741] usb 4-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
    [5.833124] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
    [5.833133] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

Comment: Please use the code button on the section above the text box to make sure those lines of code are code and not part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Add the physical addresses to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf`, like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "evdev pointer catchall"
    MatchIsPointer  "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver          "evdev"
    Option          "Phys" "usb-0000:00:14.0-10.2/input0"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "evdev keyboard catchall"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    Option          "Phys" "usb-0000:00:14.0-13.3/input0"
    Driver          "evdev"
EndSection
```

(of course, use the addresses of *your* mouse and keyboard).